# What check CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent

Tags: c#, assertions

I was reading about the method `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` in [a MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent.aspx) and according to MSDN:

> Two collections are equivalent if they have the same elements in the same quantity, but in any order. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object.

I tried the following code in Visual Studio:

```
var first = new TradeData { ID = "A", MarketPrice = 0 };
var mockFir = new TradeData { ID = "A", MarketPrice = 0 };
var collection = new List<TradeData> { first };
var mockCollection = new List<TradeData> { mockFir };
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(collection, mockCollection);
```

But I got an Exception:

> CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed

So, my question is: what exactly MSDN mean when they say that "Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object"?

Comment: `TradeData` needs to override `Equals` otherwise only references are compared.

Comment: make a lot of sense, I should of guess ,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `TradeData` class does not override `object.Equals`, the base implementation takes over, which compares two objects by reference. Although `first` and `mockFir` contain the same values they are not the same object and so they are not considered equal. If you override `Equals` in the `TradeData` class your example will work.

Comment: To explain  "Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object" more directly, MSDN tries to explain that not the instance of the collection matters, but the items inside of the collection. Your explanation is absolutely correct for this case!

Answer (score 0):

*"Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object"*

> It means that CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent uses Object.equals and not Object.ReferenceEquals. Depending on the Object type and implementation of Object.Equals, values will (rather "can") be used for comparison.

Object.Equals has the following default behaviour for the two Object types (paraphrasing):

- Value types are equal if they are of the same type and their public and private fields have the same value.
- Reference types are equal when they are the same object. For reference types a call to Equals is equivalent to a call to ReferenceEquals. Reference equality means that the object variables refer to the same object.

The assertion failed in the above code sample because you created different objects to insert in both Lists. AreEquivalent compares objects using Object.Equals method. The default implementation of equals method will return true for REference type objects only if pointing to the same object. **To compare the actual value of these objects, you will need to override the equals method for TradeData.**

It is a bummer that there is an alternate way to use comparator for CollectionAssert.AreEqual, but not so for CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243753.aspx